# lxml - keep input symbols, disable entity conversion

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, character-reference

If the following string is read and output using lxml, the umlauts are converted to entities.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring("<r><s>Die Häuser haben Dächer.</s></r>")
as_text = ET.tostring(root).decode("utf-8")
print(as_text)
```

Output:

`<r><s>Die H&#228;user haben D&#228;cher.</s></r>`

Expected output:

`<r><s>Die Häuser haben Dächer.</s></r>`

The umlauts are just an example. I generally want to disable entity conversions and instead keep the raw input symbols.

Can I disable entity conversion?
Is there a safe method to reconvert the entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default encoding used by `tostring()` is ASCII in both ElementTree and lxml.

To get the expected output, you can use `encoding="unicode"`:

```
as_text = ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode")
print(as_text)
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring
- https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring

Comment: Which encoding will I get exactly? utf-?

Comment: What if I want to save the string to a file as utf-8 regardless of the terminal's encoding? E.g. if I am on the Windows commandline.

Comment: Specify the wanted encoding of the file: `ET.ElementTree(root).write("out.xml", encoding="UTF-8")`.